# How to show a menu icon on mobile devices in Bootstrap nav?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

When I view my site on mobile, the navbar works except there is not a mobile menu icon. That is to say, if you tap the far right of the nav bar, the `<li>` elements get toggled, but there is no icon in the spot where you tap to toggle the `<li>` elements, so users will not know to do it.

Thanks in advance for any pointers, it is much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color:#e3f2fd;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                Home
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/topics">All Topics</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="/topics" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Featured Topics <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/topics/US Presidents/new">U.S. Presidents</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/topics/Astronomy/new">Astronomy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/topics/Movies/new">Movies</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/newest-quizzes">Newest Quizzes<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/create-quiz">Create</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/register">Create Account</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try exchanging the class `navbar-light` by `navbar-default` or `navbar-inverse` on your `nav` element? `navbar-light` doesn't exist in Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0):

you can style `button.navbar-toggle` to see that button

for example,

```
button.navbar-toggle {
background:#ddd !important; /* !important is just to override other styles, if any. */
}
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Bootstrap dependencies are included in the correct order. Any discrepancy will tend to break things.